# ExtJS grid panel with many columns

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Need help with grid Panel which has lots of columns.

Panel looks like:
[image]

I would like to make grid panel holder height always "100%" of grid. That it would never had "y/height" scrollbar.

My view:

```
function createGridPanel(grid_panel_json) {
  function createDataStore(data_store_json) {
    return Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields:data_store_json.fields,
        data:data_store_json.data
    });
  }

function getColumnsCount(columns) {
    return columns.length;
}

function calculateTableWidth(columns) {
    var tableWidth = 0;
    for (var index in columns)
    {
         var columnWidth = columns[index].width;
         if (columnWidth === -1)
         {
             tableWidth += 350;
         }
         else
         {
             tableWidth += columnWidth;
         }
    }
    return tableWidth;
}

var grid =  Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',
{
    autoRender: true,
    autoShow: true,
    syncRowHeight: true,
    overflowY: 'auto',
    overflowX: 'auto',
    autoHeight: true,
    store: createDataStore(grid_panel_json.data_store),
    hideHeaders: grid_panel_json.hideHeaders,
    columns: grid_panel_json.columns,
    allowDeselect: true,
    layout:
        {
            type:'fit',
            align:'stretch',
            pack:'start'
        }
});

var gridPanelHolder = new Ext.Panel(
{
    title: grid_panel_json.title,
    titleCollapse: true,
    collapseDirection: 'top',
    collapsible: grid_panel_json.collapsible,
    style:
    {
        marginBottom: '5px'
    },
    items:[
        grid
    ],
    autoHeight: true,
    autoWidth:true,
    overflowY: 'auto'
});

if (getColumnsCount(grid_panel_json.columns) > 4)
{
    grid.setWidth(calculateTableWidth(grid_panel_json.columns));
    gridPanelHolder.setAutoScroll(true);
    gridPanelHolder.doComponentLayout();
}

return gridPanelHolder;
```

}

**any ideas how can i achieve it?**

Tried lots of things with layout with overflow with autoHeight and none of them worked.

So any help would be very appreciated!

ExtJS 4.2.1